# While Loop Understanding

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm having a problem and I tried several times to solve this problem maybe you could help.
I need to modify the program below so that it asks the user to enter any number other than the number equal to the number of times they've been asked to enter a number. (i.e on the first iteration "Please enter any number other than 0" and on the second iteration "Please enter any number other than 1"m etc. etc. The program must behave accordingly exiting when the user enters the number they were asked not to.) Now the code that I have below reacts a bit differently and here's what's happening when I run it:

```
Enter a number: 4

 Please enter a number other than 4

5

 Enter a number other than 5

5

wrong

6

Enter a number other than 6

7

Enter a number other than 6
```

and this is my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int number, x=0, counter = 0;
     printf("Enter a number: ");
     scanf("%d", &number);
     printf("Please enter a number other than %d\n", number);
     while (number!=x)
     {
         scanf("%d", &x);
         while (x!=counter)
         {
             printf("Enter a number other than %d\n", x);
             scanf("%d", &counter);
             if (counter==x)
             {
                 printf("wrong\n");
                 break;
             }
         }
         if (number==x)
         {
             printf("wrong\n");
             break;
         } 
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

I really hope I explained the question correctly please let me know.

Comment: You are member for two months, it's time to learn how to [format posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Just to understand it: First you enter the number of `iterations`.  Then, you start a `counter` and ask to enter a `number` other than `counter`.  If user enters `counter`, you stop.  Otherwise, you print `wrong`.  Is that correct interpretation of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it well, you want a program that behaves like this, isn't it?

```
Please enter a number other than 0
4
Please enter a number other than 1
7
Please enter a number other than 2
8
Please enter a number other than 3
2
Please enter a number other than 4
4
** END OF PROGRAM **
```

Then, it's much more simpler than you thought...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int number, counter = 0;

     do
     {
        printf("Please enter a number other than %d\n", counter);           
        scanf("%d", &number);
     }
     while (number != counter++);
     return 0;
 }
```

---

UPDATE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int number = 0, previous;

     do
     {
        previous = number;
        printf("Please enter a number other than %d\n", previous);          
        scanf("%d", &number);
     }
     while (number != previous);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: almost. I need this
'Please enter a number other than 0
4
Please enter a number other than 4
7
Please enter a number other than 7
8
Please enter a number other than 8
2
Please enter a number other than 2
2
** END OF PROGRAM **'

Comment: as you can see on my post if I enter a number other than 5 that number is the new number where i'll be asked to input a number other than the number lol. it's hard to explain

Comment: could you explain how you managed to put it together?
I would really like to learn

Comment: It's a really easy program. You should try to infer the logic behind it. When in doubt, play you being the computer, and ask someone to play as the user that gives input to the computer (you). Ask yourself questions like "how can I remember the number I was given last time so I can compare it with the number I'm receiving now?". Or "what should happen if the number I am receiving is the same/is not the same as the number I was given last time?"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            int main()
             {
            int number, x=0, counter = 0;
            int flag = 0;
            printf("Enter a number: ");
                 scanf("%d", &number);
                 printf("Please enter a number other than %d\n", number);
                 while (number!=x)
                 {
                scanf("%d", &x);
                while (x!=counter)
                {
                    printf("Enter a number other than %d\n", x);
                    scanf("%d", &counter);
                    if (counter==x)
                    {
                        printf("wrong\n");
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (number==x || flag=1)
                {
                    printf("wrong\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            return 0;
             }
```